# Getting incompatible types error when using T[keyof T] inside a class which itself is used as a type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, typescript-generics

```
class Processor<T extends object> {
    data!: T;
    test (i : keyof T) : T[keyof T] | undefined {
        return this.data[i];
    }
}

class BaseRunner<
    T extends object,
    P extends Processor<T>
>  {
    proccessor!: P;
    constructor (proccessor : P) {
        this.proccessor = proccessor;
    }
}

class DerivedRunner<
    T extends object,
    P extends Processor<T>
> extends BaseRunner<T, P> {}

const instanceOne : typeof BaseRunner = DerivedRunner;


interface ctor<T extends object, P extends Processor<T>> {
    new(proccessor : P) : BaseRunner<T, P>
}

const instanceTwo : ctor<object, Processor<object>> = DerivedRunner;
```

The goal is to assign `DerivedRunner` class to the variable of type `BaseRunner` but it results in incompatibility error `Type 'T[keyof T] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.` with `instanceOne` due to `T[keyof T]` used as return type in the Processor class but works fine when assigned DerivedClass to the constructor interface type of BaseRunner as is the case with `instanceTwo`. As per my understand the `typeof BaseRunner` should generate the same constructor signature, so why do have this discrepancy between the two instantiations.